# Scheduled Task Implementation Using Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I need to implement some background components in an enterprise system. The components will run at a specific date/time.

What is the best way to implement using Windows Service?

Comment: Can you make the question a little more specific? You already have a good start -- implementing as a service. What are your doubts? Do you have experience writing services for Windows?

On the other hand, if it is only running from time to time, would it make more sense to simply run a console application as a Scheduled Task? This is the easier approach when you need periodic execution (as opposed to continuous execution), but the logging is not as good, IMO.

Comment: I have experience writing Windows Services but the issue is the scheduling algorithm.

Comment: What does the schedule look like? e.g. every 4 hours; at noon every day; last day of the month? at 11 minutes past the hour if the hour is odd or 13 minutes past if the hour is even?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recomment [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose. To quote the home page:

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

We are using it in a few of our products and we have been happy with it so far. We mostly use it in the exact scenario you describe - as a constantly running Windows service which periodically executes some tasks.

The documentation is very decent, the API is pleasant to work with. The features are quite rich (cron triggers, interval triggers, custom calendars, lots of other useful features). It plays well with UTC and local time (be sure to read the docs!).

Comment: Honestly, I can't tell. In most cases we schedule tasks on a daily or hourly basis, so performance of the scheduler itself is not an issue. All I can say is that we didn't run into any performance problems related to Quertz so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)?  Very strong feature set and has been around for awhile.